# sending a message from content script - google extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im trying to send a message on every content load like this:

> content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    data: "just an example"
  }, function (response) {
    console.dir(response)
  });
```

and then send a message back just to test if it works

> popup.js

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse({
        data: "example answet to the message"
    });
  });
```

but the problem is im getting undefined as a response in content. Why? 
The point of sending a message from content on page load is to set a badge with a number like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: [255, 0, 0, 255] });
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: `${blockedUsersFromStorage.split(',').length}`});
  });
```

Comment: Use a background script, since the popup script only runs while the popup window is open.

Comment: Am Im gonna be able to use browserAction on background script? Because on conent it doesnt work.

Comment: just wanted to say u saved my life :D All works as expected, THANKS!